# System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object - Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

```
    public void DownloadFile(string payloadFile)
    {
            using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
            {
                // Code removed for brevity.

                wc.DownloadProgressChanged += HandleDownloadProgress;
                wc.DownloadFileCompleted += HandleDownloadComplete;
                wc.DownloadFileAsync(uri, _downloadPath + payloadFile, payloadFile);
            }
    }

    public void HandleDownloadComplete(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs args)
    {
        string payloadFile = (string)args.UserState;
        **var file = ctx.FileProcessLogs.SingleOrDefault(d => d.FileName == payloadFile);**
        file.Status = "DOWNLOADED";
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }


    public void HandleDownloadProgress(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        string payloadFile = (string)args.UserState;
        **var file = ctx.FileProcessLogs.SingleOrDefault(d => d.FileName == payloadFile);**
        file.Status = "DOWNLOADING";
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }
```

When I run until the two lines in bold, it hits error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object. A
> common cause of this error is disposing a context that was resolved
> from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same
> context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you
> are calling Dispose() on the context, or wrapping the context in a
> using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let
> the dependency injection container take care of disposing context
> instances. Object name: 'ctx'.'

Comment: from where do you get your ctx-object? dependency-injection by asp.net? also: have you tried `await`-ing your `DownloadFileAsync`-call?

Comment: yes dependency injection

Comment: then _my_ guess is, since you're not awaiting, asp.net returns the response and _cleans up_ - which means disposing the context and everything else - before your download is done with its work. try awaiting it to check if that's the solution - and if your request can't take that long, you've got to open a _new_ context in the background task. personally, i prefer using a `HostedService` to perform anything that's happening in the background.

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Thanks, I have changed to httpclient.